# how to install roboearth in hydro

Tags: ros-hydro, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in ros. I installed hydro and i can not install roboearth in hydro.what should i do? if it is impossible, how can i create a 3D models of object?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134291/how-to-install-roboearth-in-hydro/) by [Ameneh](https://answers.ros.org/users/12576/ameneh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Roboearth has only been released for ROS Fuerte. This release won't work under Hydro.

One of our students ported parts of roboearth to hydro. Next time I see him I'll ask him if he want's to push his work to Github.

In the mean time you either could use roboearth with Fuerte or start porting it by yourself.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on 2014-04-09**:
Has there been any news on updating Roboearth to Hydro or even Groovy?